# Mongodb Pushing document into array nested in object value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, monk

Okay, well I'm building an app that uses nodejs and it has a pretty complex schema. Here's an example of what's going on there's giant document that looks like this:

```
var docJSON = {
  people:{
    funny:[{
      name:'Joe',
      height:177
    }]
  }
}
```

whenever I try to push a new object into funny It never gets pushed! No errors come up or anything.
The code I'm using right now to push into funny people is:

```
var funnyJSON = {
   name:'Paul',
   height:200,
}
mongo.get('people').update({_id:'SOME_STRING'},{
    $push:{'people.funny':funnyJSON}
},function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your _id a BSON ObjectId? If so, try the following:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

mongo.get('people').update({_id: new ObjectID('SOME_STRING')},{
    $push:{'funny':funnyJSON}
},function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have no trouble updating other fields. It's just this one that's bothering me.

Comment: have you tried `$push: {'funny': funnyJSON}` (without the preceding 'people.') ?